# "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Tags: python, css, django, web

Hello guys I have a problem when i run my app.py the css and images won't work. I already partition the static file from the template. Can you guys help me with this one. Thank you!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Villa Agency - Real Estate HTML5 Template</title>

    <link href="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/fontawesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/templatemo-villa-agency.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/owl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">
```

I already pip install bootstrap-v5 and also include the

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "bootstrap5",
    # ...
)
```

but it won't work either

Comment: Show static files settings.

Comment: Please go into your settings.py fille, and show your STATIC settings (STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS), and also, what is DEBUG set as in your settings.py file

Comment: Please also show STATIC files configurations from settings.py

Answer (score 0):

```
/Casa (myproject)
       /static
           /vendor
               /bootstrap
                   /css
                      bootstrap.min.css
           /assets
               /css
                    fontawesome.css
                    templatemo-villa-agency.css
                    owl.css
               /images
                   featured.jpg
                    ...
        /templates
           index.html
       app.py
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).